# Can't import properly in fast api project with multiple apps

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm currently learning fast api cause it's needed for a new project i'm working on,the documentation and tutorials only make their sample project with the assumption that the project is a small project,they usually have file structures similar to this :

```
- app
|  |
|   --- __init__.py
|   --- models.py
|   --- schemas.py
|   --- database.py 
| 
- main.py
```

But coming from a django background in which most of my projects will be projects with lots of models and functionality, i will definately need a way to decouple the fast api application into separate apps so i took the django approach and made my own project structure into this

```
.
└── config
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── database.py
    ├── migrations.py

└── recruiters
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── schemas.py

└── jobs
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── schemas.py

└── routers
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── job.py
    ├── recruiter.py

└── views
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── job.py
    ├── recruiter.py

└── main.py

└── sqlite.db
```

The only changes i made was to keep all views ( or repository for business logic, i choose to call it views cause that's what i'm used to) in one folder at the root directory same for routers (similar to url routes in django). The migrations.py file is my way of importing all the models in one file and running `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` as opposed to doing it in the main.py directly.

but while trying to run the project it keeps giving me errors like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PortJobs\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from routers import job,recruiter
  File "C:\Users\user\PortJobs\routers\job.py", line 4, in <module>
    from views.job import *
  File "C:\Users\user\PortJobs\views\job.py", line 1, in <module>
    from jobs.models import Job,Tag
  File "C:\Users\user\PortJobs\jobs\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Job(Base):
TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

I tried researching on the cause and most searches say it's due to my imports but after trying severally to modify my absolute imports the error still persists,and i know very well that in django it's relatively easy to import from anywhere within the project.

This is how my models.py looks like in my jobs folder looks like :

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer,String,Column,ForeignKey
from config.database import Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationships,relationship


class Job(Base):
    __tablename__="job"

    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,index=True)
    title=Column(String)
    body=Column(String)

    recruiter_id=Column(Integer,ForeignKey("recruiter.id"), primary_key=True)
    tag_id=Column(Integer,ForeignKey("tag.id"))

    poster=relationship("Recruiter",back_populates="jobs")
    tags=relationship("Tag",back_populates="posted_job")

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__="tag"

    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,index=True)
    name=Column(String)

    job_id=Column(Integer,ForeignKey("job.id"))

    posted_job=relationship("Job",back_populates="tags")
```

The schema.py for the jobs folder :

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Optional

class TagBase(BaseModel):
    name:str

class Tag(TagBase):
    class Config():
        orm_mode = True

class JobBase(BaseModel):
    title:str
    body:str
    recruiter_id:int
    tags: List[Tag]=[]

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True

class OnlyJob(BaseModel):
    title:str
    body:str
    recruiter_id:int

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True

class TagWJobs(BaseModel):
    name:str
    posted_job: List[OnlyJob]=[]

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True
```

job.py file in views folder :

```
from jobs.models import Job,Tag
from fastapi import HTTPException,status

async def create(request,db):
    new_job=Job(title=request.title,body=request.body,recruiter_id=request.recruiter_id)
    db.add(new_job)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_job)
    return new_job

async def create_list_tags(id,request,db):
    job=db.query(Job).filter(Job.id==id).first()
    if not job:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                            detail=f"Job with id {id} not found")
    created_tags=[]
    for tag in request:
        new_tag=Tag(name=tag.name,job_id=job.id)
        db.add(new_tag)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(new_tag)
        created_tags.append(new_tag)
    return created_tags

async def get_job(id,db):
    job=db.query(Job).filter(Job.id==id).first()
    if not job:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                            detail=f"Job with id {id} not found")
    return job

async def update_job(id,request,db):
    job=db.query(Job).filter(Job.id==id).first()
    if not job:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                            detail=f"Job with id {id} not found")
    job.update(request)
    db.commit()
    return job
```

and job.py file in routers folder :

```
from fastapi import APIRouter,Depends,Response,HTTPException,status
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi import File,UploadFile
from views.job import *
from jobs.schemas import *
from config.database import get_db
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session


router=APIRouter(
    prefix='/jobs',
    tags=['Jobs']
)

@router.post('/create_job',status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_job(request:OnlyJob,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return await create(request,db)

@router.post('/create_tags/{id}',status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_tags(id:int,request:List[TagWJobs],db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return await create_list_tags(id,request,db)

@router.get('/{id}',response_model=JobBase,status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def job(id:int,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return await get_job(id,db)

@router.patch('/update_job/{id}',status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def edit_job(id:int,request:JobBase,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return await update_job(id,request,db)
```

I don't know if fast api has a special way for imports or i'm doing something wrong,I just need a proper way i can decouple my code into apps and separate folders for better structure.

I also want to add my database.py and migrations.py for more clarity.

databse.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLITE_DB="sqlite:///./sqlite.db"

engine=create_engine(SQLITE_DB,connect_args={
    "check_same_thread":False
})

SessionLocal=sessionmaker(bind=engine,autocommit=False,autoflush=False,)

Base=declarative_base

def get_db():
    db=SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

migrations.py

```
from jobs.models import Job,Tag
from recruiters.models import Recruiter
from .database import Base,engine

def make_tables():
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI,Depends,Response,HTTPException
import uvicorn
from routers import job,recruiter
from config.migrations import make_tables



app=FastAPI()

make_tables()

app.include_router(job.router)
app.include_router(recruiter.router)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app,host="127.0.0.1",port=8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that exception because, Base is a function, and you cannot subclass function.
You should initialize declarative_base.

Try below,

```
# databse.py:

# Change here
Base=declarative_base

# to this.
Base=declarative_base()
```